# Images on Menubar

Tags: c#, winforms, menubar

Is it possible to place an image in the menubar in a C# winforms application?

To be clear I don't mean the drop down "sub menus" but the top level menu bar that typically goes across the top of the screen.

I am looking for ways to place an image in the top right hand corner.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to do it in code, the designer doesn't support it.  Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var item = new ToolStripLabel();
        item.Image = Properties.Resources.SampleImage;
        item.Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Right;
        item.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 20, 0);
        menuStrip1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```